# How prove this matrix inequality $\lambda_{n-1}\le\frac{n}{n-1}\min{\{a_{jj}:1\le j\le n\}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

let this Positive semi-definite
matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$,and the Characteristic values  is $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\cdots,\lambda_{n}$,such $\lambda_{1}\ge \lambda_{2}\ge\cdots\ge \lambda_{n-1}\ge\lambda_{n}\ge 0$,
and the matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ such
$$a_{11}+a_{21}+a_{31}+\cdots+a_{n1}=0$$
$$a_{12}+a_{22}+a_{32}+\cdots+a_{n2}=0$$
$$a_{13}+a_{23}+a_{33}+\cdots+a_{n3}=0$$
$$\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots$$
$$a_{1n}+a_{2n}+a_{3n}+\cdots+a_{nn}=0$$

show that
$$\lambda_{n-1}\le\dfrac{n}{n-1}\min{\{a_{jj}:1\le j\le n\}}$$

My try: this book Hint:

note this symmetry matrix
$$A-\lambda_{n-1}\left(I-\dfrac{1}{n}J\right)$$

where $J=(a_{ij}),a_{ij}=1$.
[image]
and I can't,Thank you very much

can you help me? Thank you

This book is from china  famous author.

it is well know this book problem is very very hard!and it is said this book is hardest in china linear algebra problem.

if you like,you  can download link:http://ishare.iask.sina.com.cn/f/13178572.html?from=like

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: @Potato,I have edit.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is positive semidefinite and its column sums are zero, $e=(1,\ldots,1)^\top$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_n=0$. Therefore $e$ is also an eigenvector of $B=A - \lambda_{n-1} (I-\frac1nJ)$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$. Now, for all $x\perp e$, we have $Jx=0$ and $x^\ast Ax\ge \lambda_{n-1}\|x\|^2$. Hence $x^\ast Bx\ge0$ and $B$ is positive semidefinite.

Therefore $e_i^\ast Be_i\ge0$ for each $i$, where $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$. That is, $a_{ii} - \lambda_{n-1}(1-\frac1n)\ge0$. Hence $\lambda_{n-1}\le\frac{n}{n-1}a_{ii}$ for every $i$.

Comment: Why is $x^*Ax \ge \lambda_{n-1} \|x \|^2$? $\lambda_{n-1}$ is not the smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: oh,That's my ask it,Thank you

Comment: @Sanchez This is because $x\perp e$. That is, $x$ lies inside the subspace spanned by the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{n-1}$. (Every Hermitian matrix is a normal matrix; it possesses a complete set of orthogonal eigenvectors.)

Comment: Oh,I kown,Thank you @user1551

Comment: @user1551, thanks!